# Validate field as unique with scope in cakephp

Tags: validation, cakephp, scope, unique, composite-key

I am creating a CakePHP application which have an edit form which contain one text box named air_id. In my table I am using project_id and air_id as composite primary key. So while updating air_id  I need to validate uniqueness.
My table structure is like:

```
   project_id         air_id       
       1            test@test.com  
       1            test1@test.com
```

Currently I am using cakephp3.0 and I am using validateUnique rule with scope, 
Following is my code:

```
 $validator
        ->add('air_id', [
            'unique' => [
                'rule' => ['validateUnique', ['scope' => 'project_id']],
                'provider' => 'table',
            ]
]);
```

And my controller is like this

```
$projectCustomers = $this->ProjectCustomers->newEntity($formData);
```

Now it is giving validation message every time. What I need is when I change the value test@test.com to test1@test.com it should raise the error and if I change it to some other value it should not raise the error. Is there something wrong in my validation?

Comment: Do you mean you need to make 'air_id' field unique for particular project_id?

Comment: "**_Now it is giving validation message every time when I changed the value test@test.com to test1@test.com_**" That is exactly what is expected to happen, given your tables contents where `1, test1@test.com` already exists. Please update your question with proper details describing the actual technical problem that you are facing.

Comment: @ndm  Now it is giving validation message every time. What I need is when I change the value test@test.com to test1@test.com it should raise the error and if I change it to some other value it should not raise the error.

Comment: @ManoharKhadka  Yes I need to make 'air_id' field unique for particular project_id.  I tried with build rules but it is not working because I am not using patch entity or save() function. What I am using is $projectCustomers = $this->ProjectCustomers->newEntity($formData); so in that case I think it will be better.

Comment: Also I think it is not excluding the current row from uniqueness checking. Because when I changed any other values in the form without changing the  air_id it is showing the validation error

Answer (score 2):

**CakePHP Unique Field Rules:**

We have cakephp unique field rules that might be even better:

In your table(eg. UsersTable.php):

```
 public function buildRules(RulesChecker $rules)
 {
    $rules->add($rules->isUnique(
       ['air_id', 'project_id'],
       'Your validation error here.'
    ));

    return $rules;
 }
```

At the top of your table , don't forget to include this class:

```
use Cake\ORM\RulesChecker;
```

See Here ([CakePHP Unique Fields Rules](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/validation.html#creating-unique-field-rules)).